# html5 <canvas> extremely slow on Opera 11?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, opera

We implemented graph drawing with html5's  element + JavaScript. [View it here](http://web.student.tuwien.ac.at/~e0725639/streamgraph2).

It works in Chrome 12, Firefox 3.6 and 4, and in Opera 11.

The drawing speed is fine in Chrome and Firefox when interacting with the mouse (hover and scroll to zoom) or when switching properties with the graph controls. But in **Opera** 11.11 it **takes ages** to redraw. I tried on two different machines, one with Windows and the other with Linux.

Any ideas why this is so? Or how I could find out what the problem is?

Comment: You may want to read this, and see if the profiler code may help you spot where the slowdown is. http://www.webmasterkb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/opera/6346/Opera-slow-with-certain-Javascript-sites

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I'd give you an upvote, but you didn't post as answer but as comment.

Comment: I am glad you found the problem.  I didn't have an answer which is why it was a comment, but it guided you which was the goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filling each path with `context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";` took 35ms for each of the ~200 layers in Opera.

Fortunately there was a way I could use `context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";` without destroying the visual, making the speed way closer to the one in Firefox and Chrome.

I found out by using the following two lines inspired by the profiler code, James Black posted  a link to:

```
time=new Date().getTime(); //this line before the code block to test
//code block under test
time=new Date().getTime() - time; opera.postError(time +'ms'); //this line after the code block to test
```

Note that Chrome (Webkit) already has a built in JavaScript profiler, and in Firefox the Firebug Extension also allows easy profiling. But I didn't find anything similar for Opera.